# add new column in table with value depending value of another column in same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am new in Mysql . I want to add a column in table with value depending another column value in the same table. For example I have company_table as below :

```
fldId | companyName | date
--------------------------------
  1   | adeco       | 2012-01-12    
  2   | mic         | 2001-03-09
  3   | manpower    | Null
  4   | linar       | Null
  5   | dlank       | 1999-02-28
```

I want to add 'fldState' column in this table depending on value of 'date' column. For example if value of 'date' column is not Null then value of 'fldState' should be 1 and if it's Null then value of 'fldState' should be 2. like below

```
  fldId | companyName | date        | fldState
  --------------------------------------------
  1     | adeco       | 2012-01-12  | 1
  2     | mic         | 2001-03-09  | 1 
  3     | manpower    | Null        | 2
  4     | linar       | Null        | 2
  5     | dlank       | 1999-02-28  | 1
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From your existing table, you need to create an `ALTER` statement so that you can add new column.

```
ALTER TABLE mytableName ADD fldState INT;
```

- [Adding New Column from a table](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-alter-command.htm)

After the statement has been successfully executed, you can now update all the records,

```
UPDATE  myTableName
SET     fldState = IF(date IS NULL, 2, 1)
```

Answer (score 8):

To add new new column you can use following command

```
ALTER TABLE company_table ADD fldState;
```

If you want to add those column in your wishing place . As like if you want to add fldState after companyName , Then use as like following

```
ALTER TABLE company_table ADD fldState AFTER companyName;
```

IF you want to add Column as First Column, Then use aslike following

```
ALTER TABLE company_table ADD fldState FIRST;
```

if you don't use any thing more , Then as default it will be placed at last.

Now use as like following command to Copy Column data.

```
 UPDATE company_table SET fldState = IF(date IS NULL, 2, 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure this is what you want to do - add a new column? You are violating the 3rd normal form, 3NF by introducing a column that only depends on the date.

You can read more about it on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). Basically all your columns should be dependent on the determinant of the table (the PK).

So what you can consider doing is creating that column only when you do the select:

```
SELECT .. fldState = (process date)
FROM ...
```

This would be better unless you plan to join on that column a lot, in which case speed beats the 3NF :)