# Add new column on the basis of values in the existing column in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have these columns in the table:

- id
- name
- status
- type

Status should be `0` or `1`.

- 0 for inactive
- 1 for inactive.

I want to add `status_name` field in my item listing. Is this possible?

```
$items = Item::where('type', 'test');
if(item.active == 1)
{
   // add new column status_name="active"
}
else
{
   // add new column status_name="inactive"
}

$items->get();
```

I don't want to use loop. Is there any way to do this with this query only without using loop.

Comment: this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33828769/add-new-element-in-laravel-collection-object

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to do this with loop can we do this in this query only ?

Comment: yes, but then you need to write raw SQL query with IF statement

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the items collection and apply your condition like :

```
$items = Item::where('type', 'test')->get();
foreach($items as $item){
    $item->status_name = $port->active===1?'active':'inactive';
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I want to do it without loop, condition in a query. Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

If looping through data isn't allowed you can use the [generated columns](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table-generated-columns.html) and [MySQL enumerations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/enum.html).

Create a **migration** to add the column to the table

```
php artisan make:migration add_status_name_to_items_table --table=items
```

Use **stored** generated column as below:

```
$table->enum('status_name', ['inactive', 'active'])->after('status')->storedAs("`status` + 1");
```

Or **virtual** generated column as:

```
$table->enum('status_name', ['inactive', 'active'])->after('status')->virtualAs("`status` + 1");
```

**Note that** the order of enumerated values is important and it is possible to use the index of enumerated values instead of those string values in SQL statements

```
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
| status | status_name | index of status_name |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|    -   |     NULL    |         NULL         |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|    -   |      ''     |           0          |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|    0   |  'inactive' |           1          |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
|    1   |   'active'  |           2          |
+--------+-------------+----------------------+
```

You don't need to include `status_name` in your updates or inserts, it'll be set automatically

Hope to be helpful

Comment: This is not an option when the old column needs to be dropped, because it's evaluated whenever things change in the table.

Comment: It's not mentioned in the question.
You can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14500911/add-new-column-in-table-with-value-depending-value-of-another-column-in-same-tab) and then drop the old column.
Note that altering tables lock them and it's not usually safe in production. You may alter a replication and then promote it to be the master node.
Also, consider that `status` is int and replacing it with a string column is not a good choice if you just need a simplification in the presentation layer.

Answer (score 0):

In this example, I wanted to turn a `VARCHAR` field called `curbsidePickup` that either contains "true" or "false" (strings) into a `TINYINT` field called `pickup` to make it atomary. For this, you have to iterate all items before getting rid of the old field:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class ChangeOrdersForBooleanPickup extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->boolean('pickup');
        });
        DB::table('orders')
            ->where('curbsidePickup', '=', 'true')
            ->update([
                'pickup' => true
            ]);
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('curbsidePickup');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('curbsidePickup');
        });
        DB::table('orders')
            ->where('pickup', '=', true)
            ->update([
                'curbsidePickup' => 'true'
            ]);
        Schema::table('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn('pickup');
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To add a calculated column to your results based on the value of a column, it's as simple as using the database's `IF()` function:

```php
$items = Item::select('*')
    ->selectRaw('IF(status=0,"inactive","active") AS status_name')
    ->where('type', 'test')
    ->get();
```

Another option is to alter the model so all instances will have the calculated value included:

```php
class Item extends Model {
    protected array $appends = ["status_name"];

    public function getStatusNameAttribute(): string
    {
        return $this->status ? "active" : "inactive";
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add field in table using migration

```
$table->string('status_name');
```

In controller

```
$items = Item::where('type', 'test')->get();
    foreach($items as $item){
        if($item->status== 1)
        {
          $item['status_name'] = 'active';
        } else {
          $item['status_name'] = 'inactive';
        }
   }
```

Comment: `$item['status_name'] = $item->status ? 'active' : 'inactive';`